# On focus on input how to remove/disabled validation? Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, validation

on focus, when I click on one input field I want and if it is not valid to be validation disappears, but when we move to another field the same validation appears. It means only the focus of the current field to take off.

**component.ts** code

```
createForm() {
    this.contactForm = this.fb.group({
        firstName: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(0),
        Validators.maxLength(150)]],
        lastName: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(0),
        Validators.maxLength(150)]]
    });
}
```

**component.html** code

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 pl-1">
  <label class="customer-title" for="account">
    First Name<span class="text-danger">*</span>
  </label>
  
  <input
    name="account"
    class="form-control customer-input-field"
    placeholder="First Name"
    [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': f.firstName.touched && f.firstName.errors }"
    formControlName="firstName"/>

  <div class="text-danger error-text mt-1"
    *ngIf="f.firstName.touched  && f.firstName.errors?.required">
    First Name is required
  </div>

  <div
    class="text-danger error-text mt-1"
    *ngIf="f.firstName.errors?.maxlength">
    First name must be less than 150 characters long
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont like the idea of removing validation on focus, because you will potentially allow at least one field to be invalid when a user submits his data.

It is possible with a directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from "@angular/core";
import { NgControl, ValidatorFn } from "@angular/forms";

    @Directive({
      selector: "[no-val-on-focus]"
    })
    export class NoValidationOnFocusDirective {
      constructor(
        private el: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>,
        private control: NgControl
      ) {}
    
      private validator: ValidatorFn | null = null;
    
      @HostListener("focus", ["$event"])
      public onFocus(): void {
        this.validator = this.control.control.validator;
        this.control.control.clearValidators();
        this.control.control.updateValueAndValidity();
      }
    
      @HostListener("blur", ["$event"])
      public onBlur(): void {
        this.control.control.setValidators(this.validator);
        this.control.control.updateValueAndValidity();
      }
    }
```

The proceudeure is simple:

On focus we store the validation function in a private member of the directive and clear all validators on the control.

On blur we set the validator of the control to the original function.

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-no-validation-on-focus?file=src/app/no-val-on-focus.directive.ts)

Comment: i will disabled buttons submit if field all field not valid. will this directive work with formBuilder forms?

Comment: @MichaelTomas I've added a sample to show how it works. As for validation, it will be completely disabled on the focused input, which means a user can possibly submit a invalid value if he focused that field. This is why validation should normally be enforced on all inputs, regardless of focus/blur.